# WPF GridSplitter TabHeader Positioning

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, tabcontrol

I have the following grid structure in my app:

[image: Click here to see the structure]

- 3 Rows / 3 Columns:

  - Row 0 Col 0: TabControl with 3 TabItems
  - Row 1 Col 0: GridSplitter
  - Row 2 Col 0: TabControl with 3 TabItems
  - Row 0 Col 1: Gridsplitter
  - Row 1 Col 1: -
  - Row 2 Col 1: GridSplitter
  - Row 0 Col 2: AnyControls
  - Row 1 Col 2: GridSplitter
  - Row 2 Col 2: AnyControls

I want the 2 TabHeader Groups to be aligned side by side above the horizontal GridSplitter...

Anyone any Ideas? I'm stuck here somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Set the Top Margin of the lower tab to a negative number to have it extend above of its location in the grid.  Place the GridSplitter beneath it, setting it to resize the rows and stretch horizontally (I used a blue background to make it visible).

[image: See image here]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Set the GridSplitter's ResizeDirection to Rows, and its HorizontalAlignment to Stretch -->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="2" ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue"></GridSplitter>

    <!-- Place the upper TabControl's tabs on the bottom and aligned to the right. -->
    <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Item 1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Item 2"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Item 3"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>    

    <!-- Set the lower TabControl's top margin to -30 to extend up out of its location in the grid. -->
    <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0, -30, 0, 0">
        <TabItem Header="Item 1"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Item 2"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Item 3"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>


</Grid>
```

Comment: nice work, you beat me to it.  I did edit your code slightly. I moved the `GridSplitter` up in your code so that it renders before the two `TabControl` items, achieving the OP's desired result.  This makes the `TabControl` headers appear to be 'on top' of the `GridSplitter` when everything renders on the screen.

Comment: @Stewbob, placing the GridSplitter above the TabControl's will cause it to be obstructed and prevent it from working (I just tested it).

Comment: Yes, which I thought was odd, but that’s what the OP was looking for visually.  Good to mention that it doesn’t work functionally.